# Copying multiple tables (or entire schema) from one cluster to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I understand that AWS doesn't support a direct copy from one cluster to another for a given table. We need to UNLOAD from one and then COPY to another. However this applies to a table. Does it apply to schema as well?

say I have a schema that looks like

```
some_schema

 |
  -- table1
  -- table2
  -- table3

another_schema
 |
  -- table4
  -- table5
```

and I want to copy t`some_schema` to another cluster, but don't need `another_schema`. Making a snapshot doesn't make sense if there are too many of another_schema (say, `another_schema2`, `another_schema3`, `another_schema4`, etc., each with multiple tables in it)

I know I can do `UNLOAD some_schema.table1` and then `COPY some_schema.table1`, but what can I do if I just want to copy the entire `some_schema`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe unload a schema is not available, but you have couple of options based on the size of your cluster and number of tables you like to copy to the new cluster.

1. Create a script to generate `UNLOAD` and `LOAD` commands based on your schemas you like to copy
2. Create a snapshot, restore tables selectively. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html
3. If the number of tables which will be excluded from copy is not big you can `CTAS` them with `BACKUP NO` option, thus they will not be included when you create a snapshot.

To me, option 1 looks the easiest, let me know if you need any help with that.

UPDATE :
Here is the SQL to generate `UNLOAD` statements

```
select 'unload (''select * from '||n.nspname||'.'||c.relname||''') to ''s3_location''
access_key_id ''accesskey''
secret_access_key ''secret_key''
delimiter ''your_delimiter''
PARALLEL ON
GZIP ;' as sql  
from pg_class c  
left join pg_namespace n on c.relnamespace=n.oid  
where n.nspname in ('schema1','schema2');
```

If you like to add an additional filter for tables use `c.relname` column

Comment: I know how to migrate/sync an individual table, but that mean I probably need some sort of for-loop to get all the tables I want. It does save space by not copying over the unnecessary tables in a given schema, but I feel it's kinda hard to maintain. But if that's the only way to do it, i guess it's what it is

Comment: You don't need a foot loop, updated the answer tire a SQL to create `UNLOAD` statements, you can create `LOAD`s similarly.  If you think this answers your question, please accept it. Thanks

Comment: I recommend adding a clause to limit only tables so you won't try to unload views, etc: `where n.nspname in ('schema1','schema2') AND relkind = 'r'`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with solution provided by @mdem7. I would like to provide bit different solution that I feel may be helpful to others.

There are two problems,

1. Copying the schema and table definition(meaning DDL)
2. Copying data

Here is my proposed solution,

> Copying the schema and table definition(meaning DDL)

I think, pg_dump command suit best here and it will export full schema definition in SQL file that could directly imported to another cluster.

```
pg_dump --schema-only -h your-host -U redshift-user -d redshift-database -p port > your-schema-file.sql
```

Then import the same to other cluster.

```
psql -h your-other-cluster-host -U other-cluster-username -d your-other-cluster-database-name -a -f your-schema-file.sql
```

> Copying data

As suggested in other answer, `unload` to `S3` and `Copy` from `S3` suits best.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You really only have two options -

1. What mdem7 suggested using UNLOAD/COPY.
   I don't recommend using pg_dump to get schema as it will miss the Redshift specific table settings like DIST/SORT keys + column ENCODING. 
   Check out this view instead - [Generate Table DDL](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_generate_tbl_ddl.sql)
2. The alternative is what you mentioned the restore from a snapshot (manual or automated). However, the moment the new cluster comes online (while it's still restoring), log in and drop (with cascade) all the schemas you do not want. This will stop the restore on the dropped schemas/tables. The only downside to this approach is that the new cluster needs to be the same size as the original. Which may or may not matter. If the cluster is going to be relatively long lived once it's restored and it makes sense you can resize it downwards after the restore has completed.